# Sed could not edit : not a regular file

Tags: shell, sed, find, cygwin

I have tried various solutions mentioned in SO to solve this problem i am facing.

I want to find all files recursively and change certain text.

This is the command I am using in cygwin in windows

```
 find . -not -path \*.hg\* -exec sed -i 's/FCLP1025/FCLP1080/g' {} \;
```

The result i get is

```
sed: couldn't edit ./xxx/yyy/filename: not a regular file
```

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: Does it say "filename" or is it one of the names that is special to windows, like "CON"? You probably want a `-type f` in there anyhow so you don't try and edit directories.

Comment: It is actually a mix of filename and folders. But when I add "-type f", nothing happens. There is no output and the cursor is just waiting at the next line

Comment: What type of filesystem is this?

Answer (score 6):

`find` is returning a list of all files and all directories. You should limit your search to try and find the files that actually contain the string. You could try adding:

```
find -type f ... #  Doesn't return directories
find -iname "*.txt" ... #  returns only files ending in '.txt' (case insensitive)
```

Or if you really want to get fancy, you could try only running sed on the files that actually contain the string by using grep:

```
grep -l -r 'FCLP1025' | xargs sed -i 's/FCLP1025/FCLP1080/g'
```

grep's `-r` searches recursively, and `-l` lists only the file names of the matching files. `xargs` then uses stdin an adds it as arguments to the following command, which is similar to the `{}` when using `find -exec cmd {} \;`.

Tested in bash on linux though, so if it doesn't work, you might want to see the `grep --help` in git-bash/cygwin if the flags are different. Usually they are the same though.

Comment: All of the core utils in Cygwin are built from GNU utils source code so its safe to assume there won't be any flag mismatches, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Your command would potentially find directories (and other non-regular files).  Directories are not regular files that you can edit with `sed`.

Adding the `-type f` test to the `find` command ensures that you only process regular files:

```
find . -type f -not -path \*.hg\* -exec sed -i 's/FCLP1025/FCLP1080/g' {} \;
```

or, with standard `find` options and more readable quoting,

```
find . -type f ! -path '*.hg*' -exec sed -i 's/FCLP1025/FCLP1080/g' {} \;
```

If you just want to skip any `.hg` directory completely, use `-prune` to delete them from the search path of `find`:

```
find . -name .hg -prune -type f -exec sed -i 's/FCLP1025/FCLP1080/g' {} \;
```

This makes `find` not even enter directories called `.hg`.  Your command *would* enter such directories and test everything within them with `-path`, which would be slightly inefficient.

Note that there would be no output of your `find` command as `sed -i` (`sed` doing in-place editing) never produces output to the terminal (unless there are diagnostic messages).  The output of `sed -i` goes into the files that it edits.

Also note that the last `find` command above would try to edit *every* file.  If you know something about names of the files that you'd like to edit, you may want to add `-name 'some pattern'` just before the `-exec` to restrict the running of `sed` to only these files.